# Вытянуть данные по максимальной дате и установить значение по условию

Tags: mysql, sql

В таблице **cs_reward_point_changes** есть столбцы '**user_id**', '**amount**' и '**timestamp**'. Для некоторых '**user_id**' есть несколько строк с данными с разными датами. 

Мне нужно с помощью SQL запроса выполнить два действия:
**1)** получить для каждого '**user_id**' только **одну** строку - с максимальной датой указанной в столбце '**timestamp**'.
**2)** выполнить проверку по '**timestamp**'. Если дата указанная в '**timestamp**' МЕНЬШЕ текущей даты на 400 дней, то установить в столбце '**amount**' значение равно **НОЛЬ**

Чтобы выполнить первое действие - пробую SQL запрос:
`` SELECT user_id, amount, MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM `cs_reward_point_changes` GROUP BY TIMESTAMP ``

Но он дает мне все записи для каждого '**user_id**', а не только с последней датой...

И еще как-то второе действие нужно выполнить по условию **IF timestamp** **< текущей даты на 400 дней,** **SET amount=0**

Помогите, пожалуйста, объединить это все в один запрос... Заранее благодарен за помощь

Comment: *пробую SQL запрос* Запрос некорректный. Неполная группировка, соответственно в поле amount - недетерминированная хрень. *Помогите, пожалуйста, объединить это все в один запрос...* Укажите **точную** версию сервера БД. PS. `amount` - какой тип поля?

Comment: Версия сервера: 5.5.60-MariaDB - MariaDB Server и тип поля amount - INT

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT user_id,
       CASE WHEN `timestamp` < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 400 DAY
            THEN 0
            ELSE amount
            END AS amount,
       `timestamp`
FROM cs_reward_point_changes AS t1
NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, 
           MAX(`timestamp`) AS `timestamp`
    FROM cs_reward_point_changes 
    GROUP BY 1
) AS t2
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=1eaad59ea6e316a6b4dcaeab90e4fede)

Comment: Спасибо. Попробовал данный запрос, но выдает ошибки - https://prnt.sc/ELwtzoH9g25r

Comment: @realmen80 [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119) Создайте online fiddle, воспроизводящий проблему. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/)

Comment: простите, пожалуйста. Я никогда еще не создавал online fiddle... Я открыл сайт - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9, вставил туда код SQL запроса, но там я также получаю ошибку - https://prnt.sc/JoR_1GdG8KC9 Хотя, если я правильно понял, я должен получить ссылку в браузере на выполнение этого запроса и уже потом ее вставить в сообщение... Поправьте меня, пожалуйста, если я что-то не так делаю...

Comment: @realmen80 Fiddle пустой (Вы вообще проверяли размещённую ссылку?).

Comment: @realmen80 DEMO fiddle добавлен в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Как я и написал, при вставке кода я получал ошибку и поэтому получал только ссылку на пустой Fiddle. В DEMO fiddle все работает, а я вставляю у меня в php my admin и получаю ошибки.... Почему так может быть? Вот все данные из php my admin - https://prnt.sc/PpxVvyIXYy5R Может не та версия сервера на демо. У меня Версия сервера: 5.5.60-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

Comment: @realmen80 phpMyAdmin - довольно-таки глючная поделка, славится своими закидонами. К тому же он пытается самостоятельно парсить и валидировать текст запроса, что у него получается из рук вон... если проблема носит именно такой характер, попробуй обновить его версию, может, вылечится. Ну и учитывай, что он предназначен работать с MySQL, а не с MariaDB. Да, они очень похожи в старых версиях, но различия всё одно имеются.

Comment: Ясно. Попробую обновить. У меня в столбце timestamp дата записана в формате Unix Time - в этом может быть проблема или формат в котором записана дата не имеет значения?

Comment: @realmen80 Зависимость монотонная, так что всё равно, дата-время там или количество секунд. Хотя выбор формата unixtime - странен, ибо порождает кучу геморроя. Постоянные туда-сюда преобразования, да плюс влияние зон времени, где напортачить легче лёгкого...